# Is there a way to close these empty find usage modals in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have a method in a class and I used it only once in that class. When you press CMD + B or CTRL + B or Control + Click on the function I get this empty modal. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Here is the link to screenshot https://ibb.co/YT7fG3D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.